# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine. (Use MS Access 2016)

Tags: c#-4.0, database-connection, connection-string, desktop-application, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to connect to an Access database in my C# code, but I keep receiving the error message: "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine." I have already installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable, but I'm still encountering the same error.

-------------------------------Test Code----------------------------------------------------
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Testing.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

```
      using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
      {
          connection.Open();
          MessageBox.Show("Database connection successful.");
          connection.Close();
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Database connection failed. Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
```

}

-------------------------------Test Code----------------------------------------------------